# The number of ways of seating 6 people around 2 (circular, indistinguishable) tables

Tags: combinatorics

In a textbook there is a problem asking for the number of ways of seating 6 people around 2 circular and indistinguishable tables. The textbook gives this answer:
There are 3 cases to consider:
1)5+1

2)4+2

3)3+3

In the third case, it says that the number of ways is:
$$\frac{1}{2}\left( \begin{array}{l}6\\3\end{array} \right) \times 2! \times 2! = 40
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaagKart1ev2aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbnfgDOP
% uy49vtHrhAaerbuLwBLnhiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wD
% YLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr4rNCHbGeaGqiVu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4
% rqqrFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9
% pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-xfr-xb9adbaGaaeaadaWaamaaceGaaqaaca
% qbaaGcbaWaaSaaaeaacaaIXaaabaGaaGOmaaaadaqadaabaeqabaGa
% aGOnaaqaaiaaiodaaaGaayjkaiaawMcaaiabgEna0kaaikdacaGGHa
% Gaey41aqRaaGOmaiaacgcacqGH9aqpcaaI0aGaaGimaaaa!48A9!
$$

I think it has something to do with the tables being indistinguishable, but why do we divide by 2 (or 2!)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget about the tables.

There are $\binom{6}{3}=20$ ways to choose $3$ people. This double-counts the number of ways to divide the $6$ people into two groups of $3$, for the choice of A, B, C leads to the same splitting as the choice D, E, F.  So the number of splittings is $10$.

By contrast, there are $\binom{4}{2}$ ways to split the group into $2$ parts, one with $4$ and the other with $2$. No splitting gets double-counted.

The circular permutation parts are dealt with in the usual way.

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{1}{2}{6\choose 3}$ represents the number of ways to split the $6$ people into two teams of size $3$. We consider one seating arrangement as equivalent to another if one is a rotation of the other. Henceforth, there are $2!$ unique arrangements of the three people at a given table. We see this by fixing one person in a seat, therein lies $2!$ arrangements of the other two people.  Thus $\frac{1}{2} {6\choose3}$$\times 2! \times 2!$ for both tables.

Comment: Then why don't we consider 5+1 the same as 1+5 and divide by 2!?

Comment: @AhmedAli I have edited my response.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but isn't there 2! ways to arrange the people at the first table and 2! ways to arrange the people at the second table?

Comment: I know I am being stupid but... why doesn't this apply to the first two cases as well? Isn't 5 people at the first table and 1 person at the second table the same as 1 person at the first table and 5 people at the second table?

Comment: @AhmedAli We were thinking about it correctly, but we double counted the number of teams